# Devolver valores de una tabla separadas por coma y acceder a cada valor en especifico

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una lista de `checkbox` en cual los que el usuario seleccione y mande el `form`, se guarden en un `array` y meterlos en una tabla de datos, estos se guardan como por ejemplo: `Chino, Árabe, Español`.

Al mandar un `select` para poder mostrar la configuración que el usuario selecciono, necesito acceder a cada valor en especifico, es decir, si el usuario selecciono por ejemplo el campo `Árabe` este se coloque en `checked`, al recargar la pagina.

Lo intente así pero me funciono a medias porque me manda `Warnigs` si selecciona varios idiomas o menos idiomas que lo que le paso y la idea es que sea dinámico.

```
// $data_talk el valor que devuelve la tabla.
list($region) = explode(",", trim($data_talk->idiomas,0));
```

También lo intente así:

```
$array = explode(",",trim($data_talk->idiomas));
foreach($array as $data => $key){
    print_r($key);
}
```

Devuelve los idiomas de la tabla, pero quiero acceder a cada campo para evaluar con condicionales `if` si en todos esos valores esta el idioma para imprimir `echo "checked=checked"`;

```html
<label for="4">Alemán</label>
</li>
<li class="check">
    <input id="8" class="wicket-id56" <?php //if here ?> name="language[]"  value="Arabe" type="checkbox">
<label for="8">Árabe</label>
</li>
<li class="check">
<input id="2" class="wicket-id56" name="language[]" value="Catalán" type="checkbox">
<label for="2">Catalán</label>
</li>
<li class="check">
<input id="9" class="wicket-id56" name="language[]" value="Checo" type="checkbox">
<label for="9">Checo</label>
</li>
<li class="check">
<input id="10" class="wicket-id56" name="language[]" value="Chino" type="checkbox">
<label for="10">Chino</label>
</li>
<li class="check">
<input id="30" class="wicket-id56" name="language[]" value="Coreano" type="checkbox">
<label for="30">Coreano</label>
</li>
<li class="check">
<input id="11" class="wicket-id56" name="language[]" value="Croata" type="checkbox">
<label for="11">Croata</label>
</li>
<li class="check">
<input id="12" class="wicket-id56" name="language[]" value="Danés" type="checkbox">
<label for="12">Danés</label>
</li>
```

```
//Recibe los checkbox y los inserto en otra función a la tabla simplemente
public function readData($language){        
 if (is_array($language)) {
    $selected = '';
    $num_countries = count($language);
    $current = 0;
    foreach ($language as $key => $value) {
        if ($current != $num_countries-1)
            $selected .= $value.', ';
        else
            $selected .= $value.'.';
        $current++;
    }
}
else {
    $selected = 'Debes seleccionar un país';
}
return $selected;
 }
```

Comment: Puedes agregar la parte del código que crea los checkbox?

Comment: @Jemonge ahi esta mi código, ese código lo que hace es insertar en la base de datos los inputs que el selecciono separados por comas

Comment: que te aparece con el print_r?

Comment: Los campos de la tabla por ejemplo Chino,Griego,Español. pero mi objetivo es acceder a cada valor en especifico y evaluarlo con condicionales if, para colocarlo en checked si se encuentra

Comment: ¿Por que en tu función `readData` al ultimo valor le contactenas un punto (`.`)? Me parece que seria más simple hacer `$selected = implode(',', $language);` en lugar de todo eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba pasar los idiomas a un arreglo y luego compruebas en cada input si existe el idioma con **in_array()**.

El siguiente código muestra como debería quedar:

```
<?php 

$languages = explode(", ",trim($data_talk->idiomas));

?>

<label for="4">Alemán</label>
</li>
<li class="check">
    <input id="8" class="wicket-id56" <?php  if(in_array("Arabe", $languages)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> name="language[]"  value="Arabe" type="checkbox">
<label for="8">Árabe</label>
</li>
<li class="check">
<input id="2" class="wicket-id56" <?php  if(in_array("Catalán", $languages)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  name="language[]" value="Catalán" type="checkbox">
<label for="2">Catalán</label>
</li>
<li class="check">
<input id="9" class="wicket-id56" <?php  if(in_array("Checo", $languages)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  name="language[]" value="Checo" type="checkbox">
<label for="9">Checo</label>
</li>
<li class="check">
<input id="10" class="wicket-id56" <?php  if(in_array("Chino", $languages)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  name="language[]" value="Chino" type="checkbox">
<label for="10">Chino</label>
</li>
<li class="check">
<input id="30" class="wicket-id56" <?php  if(in_array("Coreano", $languages)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  name="language[]" value="Coreano" type="checkbox">
<label for="30">Coreano</label>
</li>
<li class="check">
<input id="11" class="wicket-id56" <?php  if(in_array("Croata", $languages)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  name="language[]" value="Croata" type="checkbox">
<label for="11">Croata</label>
</li>
<li class="check">
<input id="12" class="wicket-id56" <?php  if(in_array("Danés", $languages)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  name="language[]" value="Danés" type="checkbox">
<label for="12">Danés</label>
</li>
```

Comment: Sigue sin poder funcionarme, quizas sera el explode?

Comment: y si reemplazas `", "` por `","`

Comment: Logre hacerlo, el error era MUY dificil de observarlo, porque es muy poco notorio, pero el error estaba en la función que crea los checkbox y los transforma en un array, resulta que en el echo había un " . " y deberia ser "." gracias chicos! como un simple punto puede partir la cabeza gracias @jolsalazar  por ayudarme, logre conseguir esa coma con esa separación

Comment: tu respuesta fue la correcta también Jemonge, gracias por la ayuda!